# Whats wrong with the regular expression?

Tags: android, regex

```
private boolean name_valid (String a){
    Pattern regex1=Pattern.compile("^[a-zA-Z]{3,90}$");
    Matcher matcher1 = regex1.matcher(a);
    boolean flag1= matcher1.matches();
    return flag1;
}
```

Comment: Describe what you get and what is expected.

Comment: I am doing some validations for a name ie a name can contain only alphabets thatswhy i used regex. i want a boolean value to be returned for further process...

Comment: I'm returning always "false"

Comment: Please edit your question to include expected result and actual result obtained. And maybe also what language you're using, for completeness.

Comment: Only alphabets or alphanumeric characters do you expect?

Comment: I'm expecting for alphabets..@Lion

Comment: @AshokKumar No spaces in the names? Could you give a sample name that fails validation?

Comment: @blue I'm actually calling the function from an if statement...If the pattern matches the true block works and else false block will work.. The function is returning false so my false block is executing.. I think i'm wrong with the regular expression...

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I gave "asdf" showing negative results...

Comment: If you want only alphabets with no leading and trailing spaces in the name and only a single space between each word, then give this RegExp a try `^\\p{L}+(?: \\p{L}+)*$` - a logical concise way.

Comment: Ashok, you have a _different_ problem other than what you think. As per my answer, that particular code is fine.

Answer (score 2):

You need to fully specify what input it's failing on. That should match any string that contains between 3 and 90 alpha characters.

It's probably worthwhile putting some debug code in there (or using whatever debugger you have to break at `name_valid`) so you can examine the string, such as:

```
System.out.println ("[" + a + "]");
```

But it's worthwhile mentioning that there's no point compiling a regex if you're only going to use it once. You could compile it *outside* of the function and use it multiple time but, otherwise, it's simpler just to use:

```
private boolean name_valid (String a) {
    //System.out.println ("[" + a + "]"); // Debug code
    return a.matches ("^[a-zA-Z]{3,90}$");
}
```

Based on your comments about `asdf` failing as input, there's something else wrong that you're not showing us. The following code prints `false`, `false`, `true`, `true` just fine:

```
import java.util.regex.*;

class Test {
    public static boolean name_valid_1 (String a){
        Pattern regex1 = Pattern.compile ("^[a-zA-Z]{3,90}$");
        Matcher matcher1 = regex1.matcher (a);
        boolean flag1 = matcher1.matches();
        return flag1;
    }
    public static boolean name_valid_2 (String a){
        return a.matches ("^[a-zA-Z]{3,90}$");
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println (name_valid_1 ("as"));
        System.out.println (name_valid_1 ("1111"));
        System.out.println (name_valid_1 ("asdf"));
        System.out.println (name_valid_2 ("asdf"));
    }
}
```